# why recieved ASCI contradicts scope waveform

Tags: embedded

I have written the following code,Which using USART,where in case we send 'a' to the controller  it sends back in a loop 0F which is 00001111,In case we send 'b' to the controller it send back 2F which is 00101111.
In case we send 'c' to the controller the controller sends back 4F which is 01001111.Waveforms of every case shown bellow.

The problem Is when i use PCOM or MATLAB i get a stream of the ASCII 'O'
No matter what command i send to the controller.
Where did i go wrong?
Thanks.
[image]

[image]

[image]

```
#include "em_device.h"
#include "em_cmu.h"
#include "em_gpio.h"
#include "em_usart.h"
#include "em_chip.h"
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "em_emu.h"
#include "bsp.h"
#include "bsp_trace.h"


uint8_t received_flag=0;//
// Receive data buffer
uint8_t buffer;
uint8_t tx_buffer=0x6F;
uint8_t tx_buffer_new=0x06;


void USART0_RX_IRQHandler(void)
{
    received_flag=1;
  // Get the character just received
  buffer = USART0->RXDATA;

  switch (buffer)
      {
        case 'a':

            tx_buffer_new=0x0F;
        break;

        case 'b':
            tx_buffer_new=0x2F;
        break;

        case 'c':
                    tx_buffer_new=0x4F;
         break;

        default:

        break;

      }//end switch
  // Clear the requesting interrupt before exiting the handler
  USART_IntClear(USART0, USART_IF_RXDATAV);
}



int main(void)
{
  uint32_t i;

  // Chip errata
  CHIP_Init();
  CMU_ClockEnable(cmuClock_GPIO, true);
  CMU_ClockEnable(cmuClock_USART0, true);


  //EFR32fg14 LOC2 page 157 data sheet TX P0
  GPIO_PinModeSet(gpioPortA,2, gpioModePushPull, 1);

//EFR32fg14 LOC2 page 157 data sheet RX P2
  GPIO_PinModeSet(gpioPortA,3, gpioModeInput, 0);

  GPIO_PinModeSet(gpioPortA, 5, gpioModePushPull, 1);


  // Default asynchronous initializer (115.2 Kbps, 8N1, no flow control)
  USART_InitAsync_TypeDef init = USART_INITASYNC_DEFAULT;

  // Configure and enable USART0
  USART_InitAsync(USART0, &init);
  //datasheet page 157 location2  rx portA pin3(P2) ,tx port A pin2(P0)
  USART0->ROUTELOC0 = USART_ROUTELOC0_RXLOC_LOC2 | USART_ROUTELOC0_TXLOC_LOC2;
  USART0->ROUTEPEN |= USART_ROUTEPEN_TXPEN | USART_ROUTEPEN_RXPEN;


  // Enable NVIC USART sources
  NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ(USART0_RX_IRQn);
  NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART0_RX_IRQn);
  NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ(USART0_TX_IRQn);
  NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART0_TX_IRQn);



  while (1)
  {

      if (received_flag==1)
      {
          USART_Tx(USART0,tx_buffer_new);
          USART_Tx(USART0,'\n');
          tx_buffer=tx_buffer_new;
          received_flag=0;
      }
      else
      {
          USART_Tx(USART0,tx_buffer);
                  USART_Tx(USART0,'\n');
      }
      for(i=0;i<115;i++)
      {
           GPIO_PinOutSet(gpioPortA,5);
           GPIO_PinOutClear(gpioPortA,5);
       }

    // Enable receive data valid interrupt
    USART_IntEnable(USART0, USART_IEN_RXDATAV);







  }
}
```

Comment: your  oscilloscope verifies your microcontroller code doesn't always send the same data, so it's a problem with your PC software, which you don't share.

Comment: Explain how the controller is connected to the PC.  Replace this complex program with a simple one which sends a fixed character in a loop, and get that working before you try to debug this program.

Comment: I use FTDI cable, with RX TX and GND connection.when i send a b or c the controller reacts great.but  i get only 'O'

Comment: are you sure you are using the correct baud rate?

Comment: Your "A" photo is a string of **TWO** characters 0x0F, 0x0A. Your "B" photo is a string of two characters 0x2F, 0x0A. Photo "C" is 0x4F, 0x0A. The 2nd character looks like an ASCII "newline":(linefeed). You have  serial line set for no parity, 8 data, 1 stop bit.

Comment: You might try different return characters.  0x4F is the ASCII character "O" but 0x2F and 0x0F are not printable characters.

Comment: @glen_geek No idea how you came up with that. Normal UART frames consist of 10 bits. 1 start, 8 data, 1 stop. The scope pictures look like random gibberish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code enables TX interrupt and there is no handler for it, so after transmitting a byte it jumps to execute arbitrary code or resets depending on what the default handler is.

Comment: Hello Jusme, Thank you very much.
enabling the TX interrupt without implementing the handling function did that.